# How to search particular contact in dynamics CRM?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm-2011, xrm

I tried to search for contact using fields like mobileNumber, telephone1. But When I try to see all attributes of object using following code,

```
for (var property in primaryContact) {
                        document.write(property);
                    }
```

I get output as,

```
__metadata , FullName , ContactId ,
```

I have used SDK.Rest from dynamics CRM SDK.

How to search contact in dynamics CRM using any particular attribute?

Full code,

```
//adding new_SDK.REST
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'new_SDK.REST';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

//adding new_json2
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'new_json2';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

function getFirstContactToBePrimaryContact() {

    SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords(
        "Contact",
        "$select=ContactId,FullName&$top=4",
        function (results) {
            var firstResult = results[0];
            if (firstResult != null) {
                primaryContact = results[0];

                for (var property in primaryContact) {
                    document.write(property);
                }
                document.write(primaryContact.FullName + ' ' + primaryContact.address1_telephone1);

            }
            else {
                writeMessage("No Contact records are available to set as the primary contact for the account.");
            }
        },
        errorHandler,
        function () {
            //OnComplete handler
        }
      );
}


function errorHandler(error) {
    writeMessage(error.message);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set all parameters that you want to retrieve from CRM in select part of query. On [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309461.aspx#BKMK_select) you have an example.

So it would be like:

```
SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords(
    "Contact",
    "$select=ContactId,FullName,mobilephone&$top=4",
```

For searching based on specific parameter use filter expression - [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309461.aspx#BKMK_filter).
For example:

```
/ContactSet?$filter=mobilephone eq '123456'
```

Hope this helps.